# Ошибка с DNS именем

Tags: dns

Встретился с ошибкой на новой RDS ферме. Создал новую RDS ферму HA на базе Windows Server 2016, все обновил. При попытке подключения по короткому имени terminal я получаю ошибку:

"The connection cannot be completed because the remote computer that was reached is not the one you specified. This could be caused by an outdated entry in the DNS cache. Try using the IP address of the computer instead of the name."

Ранее я уже сталкивался с данной ошибкой и решал ее одним из методов описанных в [статье](http://pyatilistnik.org/oshibka-podklyuchenie-ne-udaetsya-ustanovit-poskolku-udalennyiy-kompyuter-s-kotoryim-ustanovlena-svyaz-otlichaetsya-ot-ukazannogo-polzovatelem-eto-mozhet-byit-svyazano-s-tem-chto-zapis-v-keshe/). Но ничего не помогло, подробнее опишу инфраструктуру и что делал.

Есть кластер Vmware ESXI 6.5 на физических серверах Dell R740. Вся RDS ферма состоит из виртуальных серверов.

- Я проверил, что виртуальные машины не берут время с железного сервера, в VMware Tools это отключено
- Я проверил, что время на контроллере домена полностью совпадает с временем на серверах
- Я пробовал чистить везде кэш DNS, как на самой DNS зоне, так и локальный кэш
- Проверял утилитой dig, что запрос идет правильно к DNS серверу
- PTR записи есть для данного имени входа на RDS
- Включал логирование на DNS сервере и видел по логам, что имя корректно разрешалось
- Пробовал Linux утилитами сделать трассировку DNS, запрос идет к нужному DNS кластеру
- На самом DNS сервере имя разрешается корректно, но короткое имя так же выдает туже ошибку

Если я пытаюсь зайти по FQDN имени terminal.domain.com, то меня спокойно пускает на RDS ферму, и по IP также. Еще интересный факт, что если я подключаю VPN соединение до локальной сети, и пытаюсь зайти по короткому имени, то все работает и ошибка только в рамках внутренней локальной сети, что еще можно проверить и диагностировать. Утилита nslookup разрешает корректно, как ip так и dns имя. Буду рад любой помощи.

Еще интересно, если я просто беру это короткое имя направляю в DNS на любой компьютер, то ошибка выскакивает та же самая, видимо где то есть какое-то старое значение.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге разобрался, все дело было с SPN записью